# JavaFX webview glitches on Polymer material design elements

Tags: java, javafx, polymer, material-design

I tried to display polymer material design elements within a JAVAFX 8 webview and got some graphical glitches on a some of them.
For example, the checkbox element disappears when you click on it.

I am using the java 8 sdk update 45 on a Ubuntu 15.04 system.

Here is the code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Main extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        // load the web page
        webEngine.load("http://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-elements/demo.html");
        //add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);

    }
    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

Any idea about this?
I think the jdk webview does not fully implement all the HTML5 specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Polymer extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load(
            "http://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-elements/demo.html"
        );

        System.getProperties().list(System.out);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_60-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-ea-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b12, mixed mode)
```

OS X 10.9.5

---

The page itself is slow to initially display, but then the same page is slow to display on Safari as well (takes a few seconds to display).

[image: Polymer Image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I tried with an updated version of the jdk (same as you 1.8u60) and it seems the checkboxes have been fixed. But if you click on the menu and try the dropdown list or the toggle buttons example, you'll see there is still a lot of rendering bugs :( . Dropdown are even not usable on my linux machine.

Comment: Toggle Buttons also work fine for me (exactly the same as Safari).  Dropdown menus do not work - log a bug report for that at http://bugreport.java.com